# No Delete and Edit path in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

Im trying to put a simple link to edit and delete, but i dont see the path

rake routes output:

```
       movie_reviews POST   /movies/:movie_id/reviews(.:format)   reviews#create
    new_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/new(.:format)      reviews#new
   edit_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
        movie_review PATCH  /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                     PUT    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                     DELETE /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#destroy
              movies GET    /movies(.:format)                            movies#index
                     POST   /movies(.:format)                            movies#create
           new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)                        movies#new
          edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)                   movies#edit
               movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#show
                     PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                     PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#update
                     DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#destroy
                root GET    /                                            movies#index
```

reviews_controller:

```
def destroy
@review.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to movie_path(@movie), notice: 'Review was successfully deleted.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

movies_controller:

```
def destroy
@movie.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
```

Edit path:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_review_path(@movie, @review) %>
```

im so new in rails sir, have mercy on me, slowly please :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nahhhh i found an answer which i need to pass the `id` of `review` which i would like to be edited. Currently i'm not passing it which is causing the error.. the problem is in the path

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_review_path(@movie, @review) %>
```

change to:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_movie_review_path(@movie, review) %>
```

look similar no? i just remove the `@` from the `review` above though.. what a joke.. its dragging me for 2 days already.. but its worth it

Answer (score 1):

Its there

```
edit_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
edit_movie        GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)                   movies#edit
movie             DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)                        movies#destroy
movie_review      DELETE /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#destroy
```

Now here are the links to you need to `delete` the movie and review respectively.

```
= link_to 'Delete Movie', movie_path(@movie), method: 'delete'
= link_to 'Delete Review', movie_review_path(@movie, @review), method: 'delete'
```

Similarly to edit,

```
= link_to 'Edit Movie', edit_movie_path(@movie)
= link_to 'Delete Review', edit_movie_review_path(@movie, @review), method: 'delete'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: trying to delete a review, an error came out `No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>nil, :movie_id=>"8"} missing required keys: [:id]` .. review delete link `<%= link_to 'Delete', movie_review_path(@movie, @review), method: 'delete' %>`

Comment: What link did you use and in which action?

Comment: Your review_id is nil, is your @review is correctly setted in controller action?

Comment: @AndrewPelykh nope, its there `=> #<Review id: 41, rating: 4, comment: "1", created_at: "2017-04-21 08:52:43", updated_at: "2017-04-21 08:52:43", user_id: 1, movie_id: 7>`

Comment: but i do get this error.. `Couldn't find Review with 'id'=` .. the 'id' is not stated.. but review id is there.. the error in this line 

`def set_review
--- > @review = Review.find(params[:review_id]) <-----
end`

Comment: i change the :review_id to :id and :movie_id .. the error of `Couldn't find Review with 'id'=8` appear but its not the right id because the review_id that i want to edit/destroy was review_id of 41

Comment: Alright thx @RSB i get it..i just remove the `@` from the review and its ready to go :)